# setting window to fullscreen introduces delay

Tags: c++, sdl-2

I am making a simple game and i want to set my main window to fullscreen mode. I do this with the `SDL_SetWindowFullscreen` but it takes some time to display the window. I want to freeze the game time during that setting the window mode period. Is there any way i can get the state of the window display mode so that i can ensure when to pause and when to resume the game clock?

Thank you in advance!

First i tried pushing my own event to the SDL2 event queue, after SDL initialization. To handle the event i checked the window flags with `SDL_GetWindowFlags` against the desired fullscreen mode. If the flag is not set yet, push the own made event again. Did not work.

Then, i tried utilizing the `SDL_WINDOWEVENT_EXPOSED` and `SDL_WINDOWEVENT_FOCUS_GAINED` with flags. Something like this:

```cpp
GameMemory->starttime = SDL_GetTicks();
while(SDL_PollEvent(&GameMemory->event))
{
   // Handle Events.
   switch(GameMemory->event.window.event)
   {
       case(SDL_WINDOWEVENT_EXPOSED):
       {
           if(GameMemory->isBooting)
           {
               GameMemory->isBooting = false;
               GameMemory->isPaused  = false;
           }
           break;
       }
       case(SDL_WINDOWEVENT_FOCUS_GAINED):
       {
           if(GameMemory->isBooting == false)
           {
               GameMemory->isPaused  = false;
               SDL_ShowCursor(false);
           }
           break;
       }
       case(SDL_WINDOWEVENT_FOCUS_LOST):
       {
           if(GameMemory->isBooting == false)
           {
               GameMemory->isPaused  = true;
               SDL_ShowCursor(true);
           }
           break;
       }
       default:
           break;
   }
}
```

Did not work either.

Comment: I am no SDL expert, but wouldn't it be logical to assume that going fullscreen would trigger a `SDL_WINDOWEVENT_SIZE_CHANGED` or `SDL_WINDOWEVENT_RESIZED` event? Sequence: pause game, go fullscreen, do nothing until size change event, resume game.

Comment: Sounds like a lag from changing display resoluton, that comes from the display/GPU itself. 1. Why does the new resolution you set differs from the desktop one? They should probably be equal to avoid blurring, etc. 2. Why does the delay matter? The user will do this while in the settings menu anyway?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Yes, the display resolution is changing because the game itself is supposed to run at vga standard resolution of 640x480. The flag i am setting is not `SDL_WINDOW_FULLSCREEN_DESKTOP` but rather `SDL_WINDOW_FULLSCREEN` which is "for "real" fullscreen with a videomode change" as SDL/SDL2 documentation suggests https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL2/SDL_SetWindowFullscreen. The delay does matter, especially at game start where certain shader effects take place (like growing text etc). There is no settings menu. Certain parameters can be changed via arguments and res is not one of them.

Comment: @ErdalKüçük No, actually i failed to mention that upon window creation the `SDL_WINDOW_RESIZABLE` flag is not set. Thus, none of the events you mention ever trigger.  The `SDL_WINDOWEVENT_EXPOSED`, however does trigger when switching between modes but I am not certain when it triggers (before or after videomode change). I have to look at it, thank you for the hint!

Comment: I wouldn't change the actual resolution. Render everything to a texture of that size, then render the texture to the screen, upscaling it. This gets rid of the mode switching delays, and just doesn't look as sketchy. E.g. this theoretically lets the user run the game in windowed mode, with any window size, instead of locking them to a specific window size. This also lets you control the exact scaling algorithm, etc. Also this lets any overlays run in native resolution (steam overlay if you ever release on steam, external resource monitors...).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know where you are switching to fullscreen mode, but you should be able to pause the game time before you set the mode to fullscreen, and then resume the game time after:

```cpp
GameMemory->isPaused  = true;
SDL_SetWindowFullscreen(window, SDL_WINDOW_FULLSCREEN_DESKTOP);
GameMemory->isPaused  = false;
```

Comment: Unless the game happens to be multithreaded, changing `isPaused` like this will have no effect.